# Java ExecutorService usage

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I'd like to make a 2 threaded application like the following:

1. Create 2 threaded pool
2. Run a foo method on the #1 thread
3. Wait 2 seconds
4. Run bar method on #2 thread
5. The 2 threaded pool should wait a maximum of 20 seconds

   ```
   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
   executor.submit(() -> foo());
   executor.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   executor.submit(() -> bar());
   if (!executor.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
       executor.shutdownNow();
   ```

It's not working, what can be wrong?

Comment: If you want to require execution on separate threads, then why use a thread pool? Also, how is it not working? Also note that `awaitTermination` is not meant for *waiting* for time to elapse.

Comment: Exactly what is not working? And why are you using thread pool if you want things to happen on specific threads (this on #1 and that on #2).

Comment: It's not necessary to run on a different thread pool, the main thing is parallel running so it can be on the same thread.

Comment: @ernest_k 
How can I wait for a predefined second with ExecutorService?

Comment: I have to ask, why do you need to wait 2 seconds?

Comment: @Twi Well, you're just waiting for time to pass. You don't have to do that with executor service. (`Thread.sleep(millis)`, or `TimeUnit.....sleep(amount)`)?

Comment: @ilopezluna Because this is going to be a test that foo is waiting for something that bar will do. If bar did this, foo should return it immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Great question! I do not think you have a clear understanding of the `awaitTermination()` method. Lets take a look at this [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

The `awaitTermination()` should not be used to wait for all tasks to complete. If that is the semantic you are looking for, utilize `invokeAll()` to block until all tasks have finished. Utilization of `awaitTermination()` **without** a prior `shutdown()` is improper and could cause you to wait for a while due to `awaitTermination` not shutting down the executor.

In this scenario, you are simply attempting to force the application to wait for your thread to finish, but if it does not in your allotted time frame you want to continue. This specific case makes me question the use of multi-threading a bit because it seems a bit overly designed, but for educational purposes lets explain how one could do this.

**Basic Solution**

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
executor.submit(() -> foo());
// Thread.sleep(2000); // Wait for 2 seconds
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2); // Also waits for 2 seconds and a bit more readable
executor.submit(() -> bar());
if (!executor.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    executor.shutdownNow();
```

Although this is not ideal code, it will give you the semantics you are seeking.

**Improvement**

The `executor.submit()` will return a `Future<T>` object. This is a very strong object in Java and has a lot of capabilities. Lets see how we can improve the scenario .

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Future<T> foo = executor.submit(() -> foo());
T result = foo.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Attempt to grab the result for 2 seconds, then move on
executor.submit(() -> bar());
if (!executor.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    executor.shutdownNow();
```

Now, this is much more proper code and will give you the desired semantics with better code structure. Additionally, it will unblock early if the first future completes before 2 seconds, a bit of an improvement from the basic solution!

**Proper Shutdown**

Assuming you want to wait for 20 seconds for the `executor` to finish, here is what you could do as an additional improvement. Utilize the below code for shutdown as it is from the documentation of `ExecutorService` as an example of shutdown. Here, I have updated your wait period to 20 seconds.

```
pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
try {
    // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
    if (!pool.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
      pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
      // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
      if (!pool.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
          System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
    pool.shutdownNow();
    // Preserve interrupt status
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Comment: `awaitTermination` does not wait for tasks to finish. As its name says, it waits for the *termination*. If you didn’t invoke `shutDown` before it, termination will never happen within the specified time, so it’s just an obfuscated form of `sleep`.

Comment: @Holger Let me refactor my answer a bit for clarity

Comment: I tried the first solution and it doesn't work:
When it should sleep for 2 seconds it doesn't.
Also it always wait for the 20 seconds in every case, even if foo has returned.

Comment: @Twi The first solution is a naive approach and will always wait even if foo has returned. The second solution is the better approach and should be used. You need to refactor your shutdown to mimic the one provided as well.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a scheduled executor service? You want to run task a, you want to run task b and you want to shutdown the executor service after 20 seconds.

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
Future<?> futureA = service.submit(()->foo());
ScheduledFuture<?> futureB = service.schedule(()->bar(), 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I don't know why you want to shutdown the executor, but you can use the future to await the completion of the task.

```
Object b = futureB.get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
service.shutdown();
```